# specific volume should not block light

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

Is it possible to set a certain volume so that it does not block the light of the world wallpaper in Cycles? It is a cloud that is overhead, but not supposed to block the light from above. Yes sounds stupid but I need that in this case XD. So the object should simply not influence the environment, but should be there.

Kind regards,
Tim

Comment: have you tried to deactivate its shadow in the Object panel > Visibility > Ray Visibility?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I tried it two times, but everytime i remove the hook, Blender crashes. With the checkmark activated, it is rendered without any problems. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: mmh no I don't see what can cause this, maybe a bug in your Blender version?

Comment: Hmm really strange but i have the latest version of Blender 

Comment: yes so the latest version can still have some bugs  ;)

Comment: yeah it seems so. It just worked before it crashed again and it seems to be exactly what I need :) Then I have to take a look. Strangely enough, it seems to need more processing power than when it is checked. Maybe that will also bring the crash.